# C# Using Dynamic string or query in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to write a c# lambda expression with a dynamic where condition and trying to understand the type of content inside where condition. How can I call that content inside where clause dynamically?

I am taking string here for example

```
string query1 = "p=>p.id == 1 && p.name==\"abc\" ";
string query2 = "p=>p.id == 2 && p.name==\"def\" ";

//Normal Lambda Expression:
var details = _db.MyTable.Where(p=>p.id == 1 && p.name=="abc")

//Trying to check these if it works 
var details1 = _db.MyTable.Where(query1)

var details2 = _db.MyTable.Where(query2)
```

Comment: are you trying to do assignments inside your query? I don't think that will work.

Comment: what will be the type inside where clause? How can we dynamically assign clause?

Comment: You might be able to use dynamic linq.

Comment: How (and why) did you build that string? Might be better to fix that and go straight to building a Lambda expression.

Comment: I am trying to use single lambda expression by change my where condition based on few conditions.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries)

Answer (score 2):

Lambda expressions can use variables within their scope, so you can write it as:

```
int queryId = 1;
string queryName = "abc";
var details = _db.MyTable.Where(p=>p.id == queryId && p.name== queryName);
```

In this way you could determine what `queryID` and `queryName` were dynamically and pass them to the lambda expression. I'm also assuming you intended to check for equality with `==` rather than assign with `=`.

Comment: Also: `if (queryId != 0) details = details.Where(p=> p.id==queryID); if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryName)) details = details.Where(p => p.name == queryName);`